# Include JavaPNS in scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, java, javapns

I've spent all morning reading about JavaPNS and trying to include it in my scala project.

So far I've downloaded three jar files:

- JavaPNS_2.2.jar
- bcprov-jdk15-146.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar

According to https://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/GeneralRequirements these are required for usage of JavaPNS.

I'm stuck at how to include these correct in my scala project. I've tried to include them as libraries under File -> Project Structure in Intellij but it does not work.

Or should I include them as a dependency in this file somehow? (Build.scala) If so how?

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appName         = "My first Application"
  val appVersion      = "1.0"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
   // Add your project dependencies here,
   jdbc,
   anorm
  )


  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
   //resolvers += 
  )

}
```

Any answer are appreciated!

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to your build:

```
resolvers += "maven kungfuters" at "http://maven.kungfuters.org/content/groups/public"

libraryDependencies += "com.googlecode.javapns" % "javapns" % "2.2"
```

Or u can place all three libs into `<root>/lib` folder

Comment: and add them as libraries from that /lib folder? if i add that line "com.googlecode.javapns" % "javapns" % "2.2" does that include all three files ?

Comment: @RobertAxelsson There are two ways to add this libs into your project - by dependency on some repo or manualy adding them to your project. If you add dependency to your build it will automatically download the hole dependency graph, so yes, we can say that it includes other libs.

Comment: I'm going for the dependency way. But when I add those lines of code and compile my project. When it tries to download the library I get `unresolved dependency: com.googlecode.javapns#javapns_2.10;2.2: not found`

Comment: To resolve this dependency you should add resolver for `maven kungfuters` it works for me, so should for you

Comment: I found what caused my error. It was because I had added two %% between `"com.googlecode.javapns"` and `"javapns"`. When I removed one so it looks exactly like yours it works. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertAxelsson `%%` - adds scala binary version for cross compatibility  - `javapns_2.10`, and single `%` resolve it as it is